# operator overloading and function overloading producing ambiguous compiler error

Tags: c++, class, object, int, operator-overloading

In the given code, I am not able to understand why the compiler is producing errors when the function is called. It is passing object of `test` class which has its data member of a `test2` class

```
class Test2 {
    int y;
};

class Test {
    int x;
    Test2 t2;
public:
    operator Test2 () {return t2;}
    operator int () {return x;}
};

void fun (int x) { 
    cout << "fun(int) called";
}

void fun (Test2 t) {
    cout << "fun(Test 2) called";
}

int main() {
    Test t;
    fun(t);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're calling `fun(t)` where `t` is of type `Test`.  The only overloads of `fun()` accept an `int` or a `Test2`.   The compiler therefore looks for conversions of `Test` to other types that an overload of `fun()` will accept, and finds the `operator Test2()` and `operator int()`.    Hence both the sequences "convert `t` to `Test2` and pass that to the `fun()` that accepts a `Test2`" and "convert `t` to `int` and pass that to the `fun()` that accepts an `int`" are equally valid, and the compiler has no reason to prefer one over the other.   Hence the call `fun(t)` is diagnosed as ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not able to understand why the compiler is producing errors when the function is called

How is the compiler supposed to figure out which function to call? You have two function in the overload set associated with the name `func`, and two operators that allow for implicit conversions to types that equally well match both function parameters of this overload set.

The situation is identical to

```
void f(long);
void f(short);

f(42); // Error: both conversions int -> log and int -> short possible
```

You can fix it by e.g.

```
fun(static_cast<Test2>(t)); // be explicit on the calling side
```

or by marking one (or both) of the conversion operators as `explicit`

```
explicit operator Test2 () {return t2;}
```

which disables implicit conversions to `Test2` and requires an explicit cast as shown before.

Answer (score 0):

The call `fun(t);` is ambiguous because both overloads of `fun` are eligible for it.

This is again because `t` is a `Test` object which can be converted to both `Test2` and `int`.

Marking either one of the conversion operators as `explicit` will resolve this issue.

See [**Demo**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PncoGjzlEIBf7C2g) here.